# Android Studio - Save bitmap to gallery is incorrect

Tags: image, android-studio, bitmap, gallery, media

So I use this function to save a bitmap to gallery, but I'm beginner and it's not work.

```
public static String saveBitmapToGallery(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String title, String desc){

    return MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),bitmap, title, desc);
}
```

It's called in an AsyncTask class. I save the return value to "saveUrl" String. (I checked and it's not null.)
And in the onPostExecute I call this function (if the "saveUrl" is'n null) to refresh gallery:

```
 MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(actualMainView.getContext(), new String[]{saveUrl}, null, null);
```

The problem is that the file is not created properly. Size is 0B, title and creation date are incorrect. And the thumbnail is displayed correctly in the file manager.
What is missing to make it work? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one, maybe it helps you.**

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmatFile, String image_name) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "Image-" + image_name+ ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    Log.i("LOAD", root + fname);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmatFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great keep going @ÁdámRozinka. :)